# Using the magicline menu in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Is anyone familiar with the Magic Line jquery menu as seen on css tricks? http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

I cannot find any guide as to how to make it work in Wordpress (although lots of people mention Wordpress in the comments).

Have been trying to get it to work on a very stripped down theme but to no avail. Has anyone successfully implemented this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

When you call your menu, use this.

```
<?php $defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '', 
    'container'       => 'div', 
    'container_class' => 'nav-wrap', 
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'group', 
    'menu_id'         => '',
); ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

Basically, this will add classes and IDs to all of your menu elements that will correspond to your jquery.  You may have to fiddle with the names a bit, but if you are using a browser with developer tools installed, then it should be easy to pinpoint what each item should be named.  Also, I read somewhere where it said that the "current" feature should work by default within wordpress.